# Angular: Error: Template parse errors: Unexpected closing tag

Tags: html, angular, html-parsing

I have created a new project (using Angular CLI - 25/05/17) and copied the below HTML code into a new component.  It looks like basic HTML code - which worked as its own HTML page - but isn't compiling now that it is in Angular, which has left me scratching my head.  I've looked into this issue and it appears different for each person - some are typos in the code and others are incorrectly ordered tags.  Any ideas?

I am getting this error:

```
    Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "table". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags ("
      </th>
    </tr>
  [ERROR ->]</table>
</div>

"): ng:///AppModule/FooterbarComponent.html@24:2
Unexpected closing tag "div". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags ("
    </tr>
  </table>
[ERROR ->]</div>

<!--
"): ng:///AppModule/FooterbarComponent.html@25:0
```

And my code is:

```
<div id="footerRoot">
  <table class="footerfont" width="100%">
    <col width="75%">
    <col width="25%">
    <tr>
      <th>
        <ol class="zeroMargin breadcrumb">
          <li><a href="" target="_blank" class="link-external">State</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Accessibility</a></li>
          <li><a href="" target="_blank" class="link-external">Copyright &amp; Disclaimer</a></li>
          <li><a href="" target="_blank" class="link-external">Privacy</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sitemap</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Feedback</a></li>
        </ol>
      </th>
      <th class="footerfont">
        <div>
          © BLAH
        </div>
        <div>
          Last Updated: <time datetime="18 April 2017">18 April 2017</time>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is depreciated and was causing the HTML parsing errors:

```
 <col width="75%">
 <col width="25%">
```

Removing those and using CSS to handle column widths fixed the issue.